# Should a callback be passed null or undefined when there is no error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm hoping this is a simple question.  Which is the accepted best practice for callbacks?

**Option 1:**

```
function get (id, callback) {
    var topic = find(id);
    var err = new Error('Sorry, ' + id + ' is not a valid id.');
    err.status = 404;
    return (topic) ? callback(null, topic) : callback(err);
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
function get (id, callback) {
    var topic = find(id);
    var err = new Error('Sorry, ' + id + ' is not a valid id.');
    err.status = 404;
    return (topic) ? callback(undefined, topic) : callback(err);
}
```

Side note, find() returns **undefined**, not **null**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what do Node's various API calls do? You checked, right?

Comment: In any case, constructing an error you never pass back (in the case where `find` works) is not a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do what the Node built-in API functions do.

A trivial experiment tells me that:

- `open` passes `null` for `err` on success.
- `open` passes `null` for the data parameter on failure.

---

A couple of other points:

1. Your code is always constructing an `Error` object, even if things worked. I wouldn't do that, it's pointless.
2. Your code is *returning* the result of calling the callback. That's unusual.
3. Your code is calling the callback *synchronously* as far as I can tell. (E.g., when calling `get`, the callback will occur before `get` returns.) Usually an async call is, you know, async. If you're doing things synchronously, like `openSync` and such, put `Sync` on the name and return the value directly rather than calling a callback.

Answer (score 2):

Passing **null** as an argument deactivate **default parameter value** mechanism. If **callback** function has **default parameter values** and you send **null** for empty parameter, **callback** function going to use **null**, not default value of parameter.

```js
function multiply(a=1, b=1){
  return a*b;
}

console.log(multiply(undefined, 2));
console.log(multiply(null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The convention is `null` as seen here: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/errors/what-are-the-error-conventions.

As @T.J. Crowder says in the comment, don't construct the error if it won't be sent back.

```
function get (id, callback) {
    var topic = find(id);

    if (topic) {
        return callback(null, topic);
    }

    var err = new Error('Sorry, ' + id + ' is not a valid id.');
    err.status = 404;

    return callback(err);
}
```